# Can't browse samba network after upgrade 14.10 to install printer

Tags: printing, samba, 14.10

With 14.04 I installed a network printer, hosted on a different windows PC. Everything worked fine, but after upgrading to 14.10 I get the error that I can't print. When trying to open the properties of said printer it said

> There was a problem connecting to the CUPS server

So I wanted to reinstall the printer, and what I did before was

1. Click Windows Printer via SAMBA
2. Click "Browse..." to browse the samba network for the printer
3. Select the printer

Now in 14.10 I get stuck at the second step as the "Browse..." button is disabled. How do I enable it again?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By filling in the name or IP address of the Windows machine?  ;-)

Comment: Thats how I hacked the connection now, but it was so much easier through the samba browse dialog.

Comment: Is the `workgroup = YourWindowsWorkgroup` in your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file configured correctly?  maybe the upgrade to 14.10 broke that somehow...  (I'm still on 14.04.1 and only use LTS versions...)

Comment: What do you mean with "YourWorkgroup", because I have two workgroups in my network. Before I could press the browse and then I could see the two workgroups and I could browse them separately.

Comment: Mmmh....  Try setting it to the empty string then!  (Now I'm just grasping at straws, but it *might* just work...  Please report back after you've tried.

Comment: Didn't work. Nothing really changed. I can browse the samba network through the browser though. Eventhough only my own pc pops up, not the pc that has the printer connected to

Comment: Well, then the answer is the work-around that you found yourself: enter the name or IP address of the machine...  If you accept the answer at least other people will find the same work-around (and I agree it's not a *solution* but it's the best we've got...)

Comment: I upvoted instead, since it is not a direct answer to the posed question, but it is indeed a work-around that worked for me. It should be mentioned though that although the machine is usually running all the time, to be safe I made my router reserve the specific IP address for the printer PC, since the router is used by other devices as well. If due to a restart or a shut-down, the IP was changed I wouldn't be able to print through the *installed* printer any more as the IP was hard-coded. (I think this happened when I was fixing the lighting in that room while my PC was updating to Ub14.10)

Comment: :D :D :D ;)  I agree!